# Is this the correct way to install the latest Rails security patch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, patch

I need to install update a site to protect it from the recently discovered (Jan '12) Rails vulnerability:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ/discussion

The site I'm installing it on is running a slightly older version of rails and so I don't want to update the gem only to patch it. I've just been through this with a friend but wanted to check the wisdom of the crowd too.

**Is this the correct way to patch?**

1. Fork the version of Rails I'm currently using to a repository on my own Github account
2. Clone the repository locally
3. Apply the patch by `cd`ing into the Rails project and typing `patch -p1 < patch_filename`
4. Push the update back up to Github
5. Change my gemfile to point to my forked version of rails `gem "rails" , :git => "https://github.com/petenixey/newrailsversion"`
6. Deploy (in my case to Heroku)

Is this correct or is there anything that will go wrong in this?

Comment: I believe `3.2.11` Rails version already contains all needed security fixes, just use `gem 'rails', '3.2.11'` in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: I think you're correct but I unfortunately can't use that on the project that needs updating because it's several gem versions behind, doesn't have a test suite and I don't have time to do the upgrade and check that all works so I'd like to do the minimum necessary to get the patch in.

Comment: this will work for now. if you get to incompatible changes, that you are screwed. i would recommend providing a minimal highlevel (acceptance) test suite to cover your core functionality and then update from there and add tests to future failing parts.